# Using FFTW library on MacOSX 10.11 & XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan, fftw

I should use the FFTW library for a small program. I tried to follow several methods to get it to work, but I simply can't, since I think I lack some basic concepts.
I wanted to ask you if you could provide some step by step procedure for installing it, thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what have you tried (actions, errors etc.)?

Comment: Sure. First, I tried with Fink, installing it and installing the two fftw3 package I saw using the "fink list" command, getting ".a" files (which I searched for and understood are static libraries) under the sw/lib/ folder. Then I tried to link them with XCode but apparently wrong. Tried a similar procedure using MacPorts this time but the truth is, I don't really know what I'm doing. I'm not really a programmer so as I said I probably lack some trivial stuff which isn't treated in the "tutorials" I saw.